# Disable *.java files compilation in asp.net web site

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, visual-studio

I have some *.java files in the asp.net web site. And when I try to build web site in visual studio it fails with error

> Error 1   The CodeDom provider type
>   "Microsoft.VJSharp.VJSharpCodeProvider,
>   VJSharpCodeProvider, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" could
>   not be located.

But I don't want to compile it. The files is just to show source code in browser. The solution can be to rename the files with other extension, but may be it is possible to just disable compilation for java files. It will be the much better solution. Any ideas how to disable it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can exclude these files from project.

`Right Click on the File` and click `Exclude From Project`

Comment: Thanks. I have tried it already. It adds the .exclude extension to the file. Is it possible without renaming files? Maybe a compiler configuration in web.config can do the trick?

Comment: even if you exclude the files then what actually you have to do with the extensions what i could get from your question is the thing that you want to compile asp.net files without compiling the *.java extension files and the solution suggested above works fine

Answer (score 1):

If you want it in the solution, make sure that the build action is not set to compile:

[image]

Set it to content etc. or just remove it from the solution.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, it is not a web application, but a web site. I don't have such option in properties window.